# Flutter Firebase Firestore iOS descending problem

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a simple Flutter/Dart code that gets users ordered by lastEntranceAt with descending:true.

The problem is that this code doesn't work in the iOS emulator, but works in an Android emulator. If I remove orderBy code line it works also in the iOS emulator. Plus descending:false also works in iOS. Why am I facing this problem? Why I can't get users with descending:true in IOS? I don't receive any exception.

```
_instance
        .collection(FirestoreCol.users.name)
        .orderBy(
          "lastEntranceAt",
          descending: true,
        )
        .limit(limit)
        .get();
```

I tried it on Android emulator, worked without a problem!

I'm updating the question with code, debug result and data

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: _appBar(),
  body: _body(),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .orderBy("lastEntranceAt", descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        print(value.docs);
      });
    },
  ),
```

And [DEBUG CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzt3v.png) after I click on the button;

> Reloaded libraries in 60ms (compile: 18 ms, reload: 0 ms, reassemble: 24 ms).

And my data in Firestore
[firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3kk2.png)

And lastly, this code with no change works like a charm in Android, but in iOS nothing happens. No result, no exception, nothing.

LAST EDIT:

It got fixed by itself. Now it works fine!

Comment: Please edit the question to show what exactly is not working the way you expect by providing sample inputs and outputs. We can't see the data you're working with, so we don't know what the result should be.

Comment: the code you see works on android but doesnt work on ios. i recieve datas on android but on ios it just simply doesnt work. no error no result just nothing

Comment: Since we can't see your data and we can't see how you're examining the results, we don't know if the code is actually working the way you expect.  There needs to be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the results as you observe them.